# When deploy beta from gitlab receive an error with creating secrets

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, gitlab

Before deploy I created namespace 'site-beta' in Kubernetes.

When deploy from gitlab receive error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "/v1, Resource=secrets", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=Secret"
Name: "gitlab-registry-site-beta", Namespace: "site-beta"
from server for: "STDIN": secrets "gitlab-registry-site-beta" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:site-prod:default" cannot get resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "site-beta"
```

I dont understand why using `system:serviceaccount:site-prod:default` instead of `system:serviceaccount:site-beta:default`
I will be grateful for any thoughts on this

Comment: check your .gitlab-ci.yml file and find whether there exists something to get secret from prod namespace. The error tells your trying get secret from prod namespace.

Comment: An error occurs while executing this script: `kubectl create secret -n site-beta docker-registry gitlab-registry-site-beta --docker-server=$SERVER --docker-username=$DEPLOY_USER --docker-password=$DEPLOY_PASSWORD --docker-email=$USER_EMAIL -o yaml --dry-run`